# Integrating Oracle Java Web Start with Firefox on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, firefox, osx-mavericks, java-web-start

I would like to launch Java Web Start applications from Firefox on Mac OS X Mavericks by clicking on the link which provides the `.jnlp` file.

So far I only found a work around:

- saving the jnlp file
- opening it in finder
- right click "open with"
- then choosing Java Web Start

This is not comfortable and it seems it might be intended, because Java (here an Oracle Java 8 JRE) was downloaded from the Oracle web site and not from the app store.

Is there a better solution to integrate Java Web Start and Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this and found the solution here: http://www.ca5.uscourts.gov/docs/default-source/cm-ecf/macfirefox.pdf

Basically:

1. Click the link to the jnlp file
2. In the window that pops up, choose **Open With** and in the drop down choose **Other...**
3. From the local Hard Drive, navigate to **System > Library > Core Services > Java Web Start**
4. Tick the **Do this automatically for files like this from now on** box
5. Click **Open**

In future, jnlp links should open with Java Web Start automatically